# Package error when running r code on command line

Tags: r, rstudio

I have some code that I run that includes this part:

```
if (!require("yaml")) {
  install.packages("yaml") 
  library("yaml")
}
```

When I run in it rstudio, everything runs seamlessly and there are no bugs. However, when I try running my code on the command line, I get this error:

```
$ Rscript.exe file.R
Loading required package: yaml
Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in contrib.url(repos, type) :
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> grep -> contrib.url
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘yaml’
Execution halted
```

Comment: Read this: `trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror` and especially `repos` argument in `install.packages`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

RStudio sets a default repository when you call `install.packages` from within RStudio. When you run the script via the command line, you have to tell R which repository to use (or set a global default repository).

You can easily fix this problem by telling R to use your favorite repository.

For example, if you want to use RStudio's package repository, set `repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/"` inside the `install.packages` call.

```
if (!require("yaml")) {
  install.packages("yaml", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/") 
  library("yaml")
}
```

This should work!

Comment: This then gives me the error:
Loading required package: yaml
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Execution halted

Comment: Do you know if the package was installed or not? Do you have other code in your script? Have you tried making a test script, say `test.R` with just the line `library("yaml")` to see if the package is being loaded correctly?

Comment: For some reason I thought that error was related to the same problem. It turns out I had used a suppress warnings wrapper earlier that was hiding the real issue.